# Python json parsing genre

Tags: python, json, parsing

Hello can you please tell me how to get next values **Electronica**, **Deep House** and  **House**  from the below json.

```
{
    '1': {
        'TEXT': 'Electronica', 
        'ID': '35470'
    }, 
    '3': {
        'TEXT': 'Deep House', 
        'ID': '25647'
    }, 
    '2': {
        'TEXT': 'House', 
        'ID': '65034'
    }
}
```

here it's my code :

```
>>> for key,value in genre.iteritems():
...     print value
... 
{'TEXT': 'Electronica', 'ID': '35470'}
{'TEXT': 'Deep House', 'ID': '25647'}
{'TEXT': 'House', 'ID': '65034'}
```

I need only Electronica , Deep House and House as result

Comment: `print value['TEXT']`. It's just a dictionary, use dictionary syntax.

Comment: try `print value['TEXT']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for key, value in genre.iteritems():
print(value['TEXT'])
```

Output:

```
Electronica
Deep House
House
```

Comment: Thanks it work . Was so dumb, also this: genre['1']['TEXT']  work with same result.

Comment: @CorneaValentin: That sounds great !!. Please confirm the answer which will help others